# how do you calculate the complexity in Big-O notation? can any body explain that on this code below

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, space-complexity

```
void KeyExpansion(unsigned char key[N_KEYS], unsigned int* w)
{
    unsigned int temp;
    for(int i=0; i< N_KEYS; i++)
    {
        w[i] = (key[N_KEYS*i]<<24) + (key[N_KEYS*i+1]<<16) + (key[N_KEYS*i+2]<<8) + key[N_KEYS*i+3];
    }

    for(int i = 4; i< EXPANDED_KEY_COUNT; i++) 
    {
        temp = w[i-1];
        if(i % 4 == 0)
            temp = SubWord(RotWord(temp)) ^ Rcon[i/4];

        w[i] = temp ^ w[i-4] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you want to know how it scales if `N_KEYS` changes? Do `SubWord` or `RotWord` do anything spectacular? Do you see any reason why this should not be linear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big-O helps us do analysis based on the input. The issue with your question is that there seems to be several inputs, which may or may not relate with each other.

Input variables look like `N_KEYS`, and `EXPANDED_KEY_COUNT`. We also don't know what `SubWord()` or `RotWord()` do based on what is provided.

Since `SubWord()` and `RotWord()` aren't provided, lets assume they are constant for easy calculations.

You have basic loops and iterate over each value, so its pretty straight forward. This means you have `O(N_KEYS) + O(EXPANDED_KEY_COUNT)`. So the overall time complexity depends on two inputs, and would be bound by the larger.

If `SubWord()` or `RotWord()` do anything special that aren't constant time, then that would affect the time complexity of `O(EXPANDED_KEY_COUNT)` portion of code. You could adjust the time complexity by multiplied against it. But by the names of the methods, it sounds like their time complexity would be based on the length of the string, would would be yet another different input variable.

So this isn't a clear answer, because the question isn't fully clear, but I tried to break things down for you as best as I could.

Comment: VenomFangs, I really appreciate your help. Mainly that only one part of the algorithm. Currently, I'm working on enhancing one of the cryptography algorithms. So, i got a comment from the Examiner to justify the complexity. This is the comment " additional component to the existing structure may increase algorithm complexity, justify the specialty of the additional component in relation to the constraint of the original algorithm " so , I'm really confused what he meant about the algorithm complexity. is about the time complexity or not ?

Comment: Unless your changes improve the security time to break the cryptography, then extra work from the original will not be looked likely upon, as you do more computation for no gain. So they are asking you for a deeper purpose of your changes.